# How can I bind two Android Activities to one Service?

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to ask for some example, where two different activities (a button in the first activity opens a second activity), are communicating with one service (AIDL, etc.).

I've tried many different tutorials, but they are only about how to make one activity → one service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is probably old, but I'll try to answer it anyway...

In Android, seeing as only one `Activity` can bind to a `Service` at a time, and only one `Activity` can be shown at a time, there isn't any real reason to want to bind two Activities at a time.

But, if you'd like, the best solution is to bind the `Service` in the `onResume()` method, and unbind it in the `onPause()` method. This allows you to give two unrelated Activities access to the service, while only having one bound at a time.

Comment: indeed.... this also might help him i think, http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Local_Bound_Services_%E2%80%93_A_Worked_Example

Answer (score 3):

Each `Activity` is responsible for binding and unbinding from the `Service`. This is normally done in `onResume` / `onPause`, or `onStart` / `onStop`, depending on your requirements. One `Activity` cannot bind another `Activity` to a `Service`. That's just the way it is. :)

Comment: that's not thing i wanted to say.

Comment: i don't want one activity to bind another activity to service.
i just want to know, how to bind two activities to one service.
first activity start service, and second bind itself to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using Messenger that provide IPC communication without using AIDL. This is how you can bind multiple activities to a service.

> If you need your service to communicate with remote processes, then
> you can use a Messenger to provide the interface for your service.
> This technique allows you to perform inter-process communication (IPC)
> without the need to use AIDL.

Have a look at [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger). When you see the code, you will find a switch case within a Handler. This will cater to the multiple requests that you will send from you multiple activities/components.